# Lua - It is possible to stop inputs while "ex.sleep" is running?

Tags: input, lua, sleep

Basic stuff that I can't figure out or find in internet:
The little code I'm using for tests is simple:

```
require("ex")

a = true
b = nil

while (a == true) do
    b = io.read()
    ex.sleep(5)
    print(b)
end
```

Very simple. If I input "1" (**I am using notepad++ and windows command prompt**), it will wait 5 seconds and print it, then repeat. But my problem is... If I input more numbers during the 5 seconds of sleeping, it all will be executed automatically, in order, when the sleep ends.

Is it possible to stop that? I don't want any input being read during that time. Where these "ghost" inputs are stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can control reading by means of "buffer size" argument in bytes:

```
b = io.read(1)
```

In this case reading completes after the first byte was taken from input. Rest input bytes will be available for the next "read" statement.
Important note: if you input "1" and press "Enter" then there will be 3 bytes for reading (including "\r\n").

See https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html for details.

In addition, you want to know a way to clean input buffer before next reading. This is easy: use io.read("*line") statement as follows:

```
b = io.read("*line")  -- suppose, input is: "1234"
b = string.sub(b, 0, 1)
print(b)              -- prints 1

b = io.read("*line")  -- suppose, input is: "567"
b = string.sub(b, 0, 1)
print(b)              -- prints 5

b = io.read("*line")  -- suppose, input is: ""
b = string.sub(b, 0, 1)
print(b)              -- prints empty string
```

io.read("*line") gets whole line from input, but you can take only the first character from it.

Comment: That is actually good to know. But how could I use that to solve my problem? Like, " _Rest input bytes will be available for the next "read" statement_ ", that is the thing, I don't want it to be available. 

Is it possible to clean any input before calling the io.read()?

Comment: I have extended my answer for this case

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but when I tried to run your code, it got stuck in the loop. Perhaps it is something with my Lua?

Comment: I am sorry. You have correct version of Lua )). I have made code modifications to show the better way.